# How to use fields_get method to edit view?

Tags: python, odoo

I'm trying to achieve similar effect as to the Invoice Line form where certain columns appear or disappear (edit view?) based on a selection in the drop down list.

I'm trying to study the code in account_invoice_layout that achieves this effect but its a bit difficult to understand.

Here's the full code:

```
class account_invoice_line(osv.osv):

def move_line_get_item(self, cr, uid, line, context=None):
    if line.state != 'article':
        return None
    return super(account_invoice_line, self).move_line_get_item(cr, uid, line, context)

def fields_get(self, cr, uid, fields=None, context=None):
    article = {
        'article': [('readonly', False), ('invisible', False)],
        'text': [('readonly', True), ('invisible', True), ('required', False)],
        'subtotal': [('readonly', True), ('invisible', True), ('required', False)],
        'title': [('readonly', True), ('invisible', True), ('required', False)],
        'break': [('readonly', True), ('invisible', True), ('required', False)],
        'line': [('readonly', True), ('invisible', True), ('required', False)],
    }
    states = {
        'name': {
            'break': [('readonly', True),('required', False),('invisible', True)],
            'line': [('readonly', True),('required', False),('invisible', True)],
            },
        'product_id': article,
        'account_id': article,
        'quantity': article,
        'uos_id': article,
        'price_unit': article,
        'discount': article,
        'invoice_line_tax_id': article,
        'account_analytic_id': article,
    }
    res = super(account_invoice_line, self).fields_get(cr, uid, fields, context)
    for field in res:
        if states.has_key(field):
            for key,value in states[field].items():
                res[field].setdefault('states',{})
                res[field]['states'][key] = value
    return res

def onchange_invoice_line_view(self, cr, uid, id, type, context=None, *args):

    if (not type):
        return {}
    if type != 'article':
        temp = {'value': {
                'product_id': False,
                'uos_id': False,
                'account_id': False,
                'price_unit': False,
                'price_subtotal': False,
                'quantity': 0,
                'discount': False,
                'invoice_line_tax_id': False,
                'account_analytic_id': False,
                },
            }
        if type == 'line':
            temp['value']['name'] = ' '
        if type == 'break':
            temp['value']['name'] = ' '
        if type == 'subtotal':
            temp['value']['name'] = 'Sub Total'
        return temp
    return {}

def create(self, cr, user, vals, context=None):
    if vals.has_key('state'):
        if vals['state'] == 'line':
            vals['name'] = ' '
        if vals['state'] == 'break':
            vals['name'] = ' '
        if vals['state'] != 'article':
            vals['quantity']= 0
            vals['account_id']= self._default_account(cr, user, None)
    return super(account_invoice_line, self).create(cr, user, vals, context)

def write(self, cr, user, ids, vals, context=None):
    if vals.has_key('state'):
        if vals['state'] != 'article':
            vals['product_id']= False
            vals['uos_id']= False
            vals['account_id']= self._default_account(cr, user, None)
            vals['price_unit']= False
            vals['price_subtotal']= False
            vals['quantity']= 0
            vals['discount']= False
            vals['invoice_line_tax_id']= False
            vals['account_analytic_id']= False
        if vals['state'] == 'line':
            vals['name'] = ' '
        if vals['state'] == 'break':
            vals['name'] = ' '
    return super(account_invoice_line, self).write(cr, user, ids, vals, context)

def copy_data(self, cr, uid, id, default=None, context=None):
    if default is None:
        default = {}
    default['state'] = self.browse(cr, uid, id, context=context).state
    return super(account_invoice_line, self).copy_data(cr, uid, id, default, context)

def _fnct(self, cr, uid, ids, name, args, context=None):
    res = {}
    lines = self.browse(cr, uid, ids, context=context)
    account_ids = [line.account_id.id for line in lines]
    account_names = dict(self.pool.get('account.account').name_get(cr, uid, account_ids, context=context))
    for line in lines:
        if line.state != 'article':
            if line.state == 'line':
                res[line.id] = '-----------------------------------------'
            elif line.state == 'break':
                res[line.id] = 'PAGE BREAK'
            else:
                res[line.id] = ' '
        else:
            res[line.id] = account_names.get(line.account_id.id, '')
    return res

_name = "account.invoice.line"
_order = "invoice_id, sequence asc"
_description = "Invoice Line"
_inherit = "account.invoice.line"
_columns = {
    'state': fields.selection([
            ('article','Product'),
            ('title','Title'),
            ('text','Note'),
            ('subtotal','Sub Total'),
            ('line','Separator Line'),
            ('break','Page Break'),]
        ,'Type', select=True, required=True),
    'sequence': fields.integer('Sequence Number', select=True, help="Gives the sequence order when displaying a list of invoice lines."),
    'functional_field': fields.function(_fnct, arg=None, fnct_inv=None, fnct_inv_arg=None, type='char', fnct_search=None, obj=None, store=False, string="Source Account"),
}

def _default_account(self, cr, uid, context=None):
    cr.execute("select id from account_account where parent_id IS NULL LIMIT 1")
    res = cr.fetchone()
    return res[0]

_defaults = {
    'state': 'article',
    'sequence': 0,
}
```

account_invoice_line()

What does the fields_get method do exactly? When is it executed? How does the above code manage to edit the view?

Thank You.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In fact fields_get() returns the fields definition of the module. On Fields definition, you can supply a states argument.

By default, it works like this on a field definition :

```
states = {'draft':[('readonly','=',True)]}
```

It puts the field on readonly when the state form is at 'draft'.

the variables ***states*** and ***articles*** store the same values.

Now in the module you show us, state field values are diffrent from usual values :

```
[('article','Product'),
            ('title','Title'),
            ('text','Note'),
            ('subtotal','Sub Total'),
            ('line','Separator Line'),
            ('break','Page Break'),]
```

In the last part of the fields_get() function, we have :

```
res = super(account_invoice_line, self).fields_get(cr, uid, fields, context)
for field in res:
    if states.has_key(field):
        for key,value in states[field].items():
            res[field].setdefault('states',{})
            res[field]['states'][key] = value
return res
```

It uses the method of the super class, it works like this :

the fields_get() returns, with the fields argument, the fields that exist on the module. **Your module just force the state argument of each field.**

Finally, it permits to display fields according to a fictif state field.
In Your example :

- If a line is at 'article' state, it's displays by default,
- If a line is at 'title' state, it's display invisible and readonly.

i think those states values are here to tell if a line is a title, an article or others.

So, if you want to do the same in your own module, copy/paste this fields_get() function definition, **customize your article and states variables** and don't forget to adapt, if needed, the **state field definition** on the _columns class attributes.

Hope i helped you,

Nonow